# Dynamically create multiple div from existing div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a div having 2 labels and 1 dropdownlist with name divInfo.

Now I want to create multiple div from this divInfo using Code behind.

I try to do this by creating a div dynamically in loop eg. divDynamic and then assignd by divInfo.

```
divDynamic = divInfo
```

But it doesn't remain for render and display only one div.

Comment: Please add relevant parts of your existing code to the question.

Comment: More specific question would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by fetching the html of the div and assigning it to a literal control

```
//create a literal to hold the div content

var sb = new StringBuilder();

//get all the contents of div
divInfo.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));


 Literal ldiv = new Literal();
  ldiv.Text = sb.ToString();
```